# The common practice for polling inside Windows services

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-services, long-polling

Usually you're adviced to use something like that (using timeouts):

```
Thread workerThread = null;
AutoResetEvent finishedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
    this.finishedEvent.Reset();
    this.workerThread = new Thread(this.Poll);
    this.workerThread.Start();
}

protected override void OnStop() {
    this.finishedEvent.Set();
    if(!this.workerThread.Join(2000)) {
        this.RequestAdditionalTime(5000);
    }
}
```

where `Poll` function is defined like:

```
private void Poll() {
    try {
        var timeout = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pollingTimeout"]);
        while(!this.finishedEvent.WaitOne(timeout, false)) {
            // do polling
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { 
        Logger.Log.Fatal(ex); 
        throw; 
    }
}
```

1. Are these constructs essentially equal:

   `while(!this.finishedEvent.WaitOne(0, false))`

   and

   `while(true)` with no `finishedEvent`?
2. I've read that timeouts are used to reduce the cpu usage. Is it a bad choice to use polling without timeouts?

Comment: No, they are not equivalent.  You'll never be able to stop the service with the while(true) loop.  And you'll burn 100% core, accomplishing about nothing.  Polling is bad but sometimes you just don't have a choice because you can't get an event to tell you that something interesting happened.  Depends.

Comment: Ok, I understand! So using `AutoResetEvent` when you're on the separate (worker) thread is the way to signal the service to **stop** / **start**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very simple way to do this providing you don't strictly need an orderly shutdown.  If you mark the `workerThread` as a [background thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx), it will shut down automatically when the service stops.  In this example, you can forego the use of the `finishedEvent` and use an infinite loop.  For example,

```
Thread workerThread = null;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    this.workerThread = new Thread(this.DoWork);
    // Signal the thread to stop automatically when the process exits.
    this.workerThread.IsBackground = true;
    this.workerThread.Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
}

private void DoWork()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // do your work here...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle exception here...
    }
}
```

Note that this approach should only be used if the work you are doing can be interrupted at any point without adverse effects.  Let's say for an example that you were writing data to an Excel spreadsheet.  Once the the Windows service exits, the thread represented by your `DoWork()` method will also exit immediately.  If it is in the middle of adding data to the spreadsheet, it is very likely that the spreadsheet could have incomplete information or, worse case, might even be in a state that it cannot be opened in Excel.  The point is, this approach *could* be used, but only in certain circumstances.

A better approach would be to fully transition to an event-based mechanism.  It is much more efficient than polling, and it allows for an orderly shutdown to your service.  Below is an example with comments.

```
Thread _workThread = null;
// I use ManualResetEvent instead of AutoResetEvent because I do NOT want
// this event to EVER reset.  It is meant to be set exactly one time.
ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _workThread = new Thread(DoWork());
    _workThread.Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    // Trigger the DoWork() method, i.e., the _workThread, to exit.
    _shutdownEvent.Set();

    // I always shutdown my service by simply joining the work thread.
    // There are probably more advanced techniques that take into account
    // longer shutdown cycles, but I design my worker thread(s) to have
    // tight work cycles so that the shutdownEvent is examined frequently
    // enough to facilitate timely shutdowns.
    _workThread.Join();
}
```

Now let's look at the details of the `DoWork()` method.  For this example, I'm gonna use a timer to illustrate the event-based approach.  Note that this illustration is not substantively different from calling the `WaitOne()` method with a timeout.  However, if the work to be done involves processing input from other threads, e.g., a thread that receives data from a network socket or a thread that reads data from a database, this approach easily accommodates those scenarios.

```
// Creature of habit.  AutoResetEvent would probably work for this event,
// but I prefer to manually control when the event resets.
ManualResetEvent _timerElapsedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
System.Timers.Timer _timer = null;

private void DoWork() {
    try {
        // Create, configure, and start the timer to elapse every second and
        // require a manual restart (again, I prefer the manual control).
        // Note when the timer elapses, it sets the _timerElapsedEvent.
        _timer = new Timer(1000) { AutoReset = false };
        _timer.Elapsed =+ (sender, e) => _timerElapsedEvent.Set();
        _timer.Start();

        // Create a WaitHandle array that contains the _shutdownEvent and
        // the _timerElapsedEvent...in that order!
        WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[] { _shutdownEvent, _timerElapsedEvent };

        // Employ the event-based mechanism.
        while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0)) {
            switch (WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles) {
                case 0:
                    // This case handles when the _shutdownEvent occurs,
                    // which will cause the while loop to exit.
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // This case handles when the _timerElapsedEvent occurs.
                    // Do the work, reset the event, and restart the timer.
                    DoProcessing();
                    _timerElapsedEvent.Reset();
                    _timer.Start();
                    break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle exception here...
    }
}
```

The [`WaitHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle(v=vs.110).aspx) array is what makes the event-based mechanism possible.  When you create the array, **always** be sure to add the events to the array in priority order.  This is why the `_shutdownEvent` is listed *before* the `_timerElapsedEvent`.  If the events were reversed in the array, it is possible that the `_shutdownEvent` would never get processed.  You can add as many events to the `WaitHandle` array as necessary.  That's what makes this approach so flexible.

Last thought.  To facilitate timely shutdowns of your service, you want to make sure that work to be done when the `_timerElapsedEvent` is triggered doesn't take too long.  In other words, the `_shutdownEvent` will not be checked by the `while` loop until the `DoProcessing()` method exits.  So you'll want to limit the amount of time you spend inside the `DoProcessing()` method.  If that method is long-running, then you'll probably want to check the `_shutdownEvent` inside `DoProcessing()` and exit at strategic points when the service has indicated it is shutting down.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you for your answer. God bless you in Jesus name!

Comment: You, too, brother.  ;-)